# Implement a random positioning but to also cover the viewport in React/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, gsap, preloader

I've got a bunch of images flashing on a preloader screen of a Next.js application with GSAP like a collage and I'm using a `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px` to randomly splatter them on the screen. The issue I'm have is that although it works very well, 'random' doesn't mean it covers the entire screen and it often leave gaps in the view. Is there a way of still assigning random positioning but also covering the entire the viewport?

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { gsap, Linear } from 'gsap'
import imagesLoaded from 'imagesloaded'
import styles from '../../styles/Preloader.module.scss'
import ScrollContext from "../Context"

const images = [
    {
        src: "/preloader/img.png",
        landscape: true,
        alt: "Code",
        styles: {
            position: "relative",
            top: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px`,
            left: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.6)* 900)}px`
        }
    },
    {
        src: "/preloader/img.png",
        landscape: true,
        alt: "Styleguide",
        styles: {
            position: "relative",
            top: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px`,
            left: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.6)* 900)}px`
        }
    },
    {
        src: "/preloader/img.png",
        landscape: true,
        alt: "Office",
        styles: {
            position: "relative",
            top: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px`,
            left: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.6)* 900)}px`
        }
    },
    {
        src: "/preloader/img.png",
        landscape: true,
        alt: "Device screens",
        styles: {
            position: "relative",
            top: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px`,
            left: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.6)* 900)}px`
        }
    },
    {
        src: "/preloader/img.png",
        landscape: true,
        alt: "Zoom meetings",
        styles: {
            position: "relative",
            top: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.5)* 500)}px`,
            left: `${Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.6)* 900)}px`
        }
    },
]

const Preloader = () => {
    let [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const scrollingStatus = useContext(ScrollContext);
    const {scrolable, setScrollable} = scrollingStatus;
    const indicatorRef = useRef(null);
    const welcomeRef = useRef(null);
    const imgRef = useRef(null);
    const TLImages = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });
    const [rendered, setRendered] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setRendered(true)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
            document.body.style.overflowY = scrolable ? "auto" : "hidden";
        }
        console.log(scrolable)
    }, [scrolable]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (welcomeRef.current) {
            gsap.fromTo(welcomeRef.current, { alpha: 0, duration: 40 }, { alpha: 1 });
            setScrollable(false);
        }

        TLImages.to(".imagesWrapper", { alpha: 1, ease: Linear.easeNone });
        TLImages.add(
            gsap.fromTo(
                ".images",
                { visibility: "hidden", stagger: 0.5 },
                { visibility: "visible", stagger: 0.5 }
            )
        );
        TLImages.add(
            gsap.to(".preloader", {
                alpha: 0,
                onComplete: function () {
                    setScrollable(true); //scroll for the rest of the home page
                },
            })
        );
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let loadedCount = 0;
            let loadingProgress = 0;
            var imgLoad = imagesLoaded("#__next");

            if (imgLoad.images.length === 0) {
                loadingProgress = 100;
                doneLoading();
            }

            imgLoad.on("progress", function (instance) {
                var imagesToLoad = instance.images.length;
                loadProgress(imagesToLoad);
            });

            function loadProgress(imagesToLoad) {
                loadedCount++;
                loadingProgress = (loadedCount / imagesToLoad) * 100;
                setProgress(loadingProgress);

                if (loadingProgress === 100) {
                    doneLoading();
                }
            }

            function doneLoading() {
                gsap.to(indicatorRef.current, {
                    width: "100%",
                    onComplete: function () {
                        gsap.to(welcomeRef.current, {
                            alpha: 0,
                            duration: 0.4,
                            onComplete: function () {
                                TLImages.play();
                            },
                        });
                    },
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={`${styles.preloader_container} preloader`} style={scrolable ? { zIndex: "-1" } : {zIndex: "99999"}}>
            <div className={styles.preloader_wrapper}>
                <div className={styles.preloader_inner_wrapper}>
                    <div className={styles.future} ref={welcomeRef}>
                        <p className={styles.mid_uppercase}>Do you want to see what the future of digital services looks like?</p>
                        <div className={styles.progress_bar}>
                            <div className={styles.progress} ref={indicatorRef}></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={`${styles.images} imagesWrapper`}>
                        <div className={styles.imagesInner}>
                            {images.map((item, idx) => (
                                <figure
                                    ref={imgRef}
                                    className={`${styles.figure} ${item.landscape ? styles.landscape : styles.portrait} images`}
                                    key={`img-${idx}`}
                                >
                                    <img src={item.src} alt={item.alt} style={rendered ? item.styles : {}} className={styles.image} />
                                </figure>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Preloader
```

Comment: I would decide on a range of sizes for each image, would then draw a grid that makes sure even the smallest of sizes will cover the screen, then randomize the sizes and positions within that range.

Comment: You should read up about packing algorithms.